# How to show scan and map topic simultaneously in rviz

Tags: navigation, rviz, scan, map-server, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am currently running localization in a static map using hokuyo laser range finder. I am running both amcl and laser scan matcher nodes. I would like to view the laser scan data on rviz to check whether it fits with the static map. However, I found that once I tried to display the scan topic on rviz together with map, rviz will crash and end instantly. I found that this is caused by the transformation of the laser to map frame and this transformation is provided by the laser scan matcher node. May I know how do I solve this problem? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131231/how-to-show-scan-and-map-topic-simultaneously-in-rviz/) by [zero1985](https://answers.ros.org/users/6926/zero1985/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2014-02-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is due to the version of rviz. Rviz 1.9.34 seems to have problem to show laser scan and hence upgrading to Rviz 1.9.35 solve this problem. Manual upgrading of rviz can be done by git cloning ros visualization to your catkin workspace and git checkout 1.9.45 it. After that just catkin_make and it should be done. Closing this topic

---

Originally posted by [zero1985](https://answers.ros.org/users/6926/zero1985/) with karma: 100 on 2014-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1